# how to determine which class of element have a number inside it

Tags: jquery, css, class

I want to find which class have a number inside it and get it via jquery.
I know there could be used data attribute, but I need to implement className+number solution.

I guess it could be simple, but can not find an answer.

I tried to use regex like:

1) `$(this).attr('class').match(/\d+/)[0];` and

2) `$(this).attr('class').match(/number-\d+)/)[0];`

Both regex works but they get only value of #works, not of #doesnot. 
I guess it is because second div has 2 classes (in my case I will have lots of elements with several classes with similar beginning).

My code (just for referral):

```
<div>
   <div id="works" class="number-1"></div>
   <div id="doesnot" class="second number-2"></div>
</div>
```

Please advice, how could I select only a class with number (from several classes) and get that number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer just using `.test()` for my JavaScript/jQuery RegEX. Personally feels cleaner and easier to write. All I do is get the classList of the element (returns an array) and loop through them, checking them against the pattern.

I made an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yjhgswfn/2/) but the code is:

The JS

```
$('div').each(function()
{
    let classes = $(this).prop('classList');

    $.each(classes, function(i, val)
    {
        if (/number-\d/.test(val)) console.log(val)
    })
});
```

The HTML

```
<div class="element-1 element-23 treybake">
    <span>Hello, world</span>
</div>

<div class="element">
    <span>Goodbye, world</span>
</div>
```

essentially we match the class string against `\d` which is:

> Matches a digit character. Equivalent to [0-9].
>   For example, /\d/ or /[0-9]/ matches '2' in "B2 is the suite number."

source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Thank you very much. Maybe I was not clear enough. My first element has 2 (or more) classes, but only 1 of them has a number inside it. I need to get only that class (it begins with 'number-') with number and get that number. Should I loop inside that element? Your modified code https://jsfiddle.net/yjhgswfn/1/ shows true even if there is any class without a number if another has it inside.

Comment: Ah I see - you're more trying to *extract* the class name from the class list - are you storing it in a variable?

Comment: @Skaidrius kk uno momento! :)

Comment: Thank you. I got the point and what I wanted is this code https://jsfiddle.net/yjhgswfn/4/ based on yours. Could you change yours a bit acc to mine and I will point it as correct ;) Now I will try to implement it to real example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186196/discussion-between-skaidrius-and-treybake).